# adding Macports directories to Clang search path

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, macports

I'm running OSX (Mountain Lion), and developing using clang on Xcode. I'm currently using macports as a package manager. Is there a way to add the macports include and lib directories (/opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib) to the default clang search paths, or even to the default Xcode search paths, so I don't have to reconfigure every time I create a new project? Otherwise, do any of the alternatives(fink/homebrew) install into standard locations?

Comment: You can make default-template project with this libraries pre-settuped. However I prefer cmake to generate Xcode project, in this case you can tune anything you want.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting up CMake for a project like this, I don't want to maintain it. I'm rapidly creating new smaller projects and it's slowing me down hugely,. Are there any resources for creating a new template? I'm using Xcode 5.